# Add solution folder to visual studio project template

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, project-template

Is it possible to add a solution folders with the project template? If it's not built in functionality, is it possible to create a custom task for this?

Answer (score 2):

This is bit tricky. You cannot do this with simple project template. Project templates could operate only on single project level. To implement more advanced logic, you need to implement [WizardExtension](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171411.aspx) and register it within `.vstemplate` file of your template.

```
<WizardExtension>
    <Assembly>AssemblyInGACWithSomeLogic</Assembly>
    <FullClassName>MySuperWizardExtension</FullClassName>
</WizardExtension>
```

You can find more about wizard extensions on [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185301.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

It is possible, for how to you can check this [msdn](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s365byhx.aspx) website.
Or for the [total overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6db0hwky.aspx)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it using template wizards. I guess that you already know how to implement it.

So, inside RunFinished method, write these lines:

```
    var destFolder = Directory.GetParent(path).Parent;
    System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(destFolder.FullName + "\\.nuget");
    ((Solution2) _dte.Solution).AddSolutionFolder(destFolder.FullName + "\\.nuget");
```

For Solution2 class you have to reference EnvDTE80.dll.
_dte must be set from RunStarted method.

```
private DTE _dte;
public void RunStarted(object automationObject, Dictionary<string, string> replacementsDictionary, WizardRunKind runKind, object[] customParams)
{
     _dte = (DTE)automationObject;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Just simply add `<SolutionFolder>...</SolutionFolder>` in the .vstemplate file

```
<SolutionFolder Name="Math Classes">
        <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="MyFolder1">
            3rdpartyProj\MyTemplate.vstemplate
        </ProjectTemplateLink>
        <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="MyFolder2">
            3rdpartyProj\MyTemplate.vstemplate
        </ProjectTemplateLink>
    </SolutionFolder>
```

References: [SolutionFolder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/extensibility/solutionfolder-element-visual-studio-templates?view=vs-2015)

Answer (score -3):

I'm using the following snippets in my Project Template Wizard (see Mike Chaliy's answer):

```
        private static SolutionFolder GetSolutionFolder(Solution2 solution) {
        var project = GetSolutionFolderProject(solution);
        return (SolutionFolder) project.Object;
    }

    private static Project GetSolutionFolderProject(Solution2 solution) {
        var project =
            solution.Projects.Cast<Project>().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "Solution Items");
        if (project == null) project = solution.AddSolutionFolder("Solution Items");
        return project;
    }
```

where`_solution = (Solution2) _dte.Solution;`

Comment: Ok, do you mind posting your complete IWizard implementation? I don't understand where I should call the GetSolutionFolder method?

Comment: public void RunStarted(object application, Dictionary<string, string> replacementsDictionary, WizardRunKind runKind, object[] customParams) {
   _dte = application as _DTE;
   _solution = (Solution2) _dte.Solution;
   _solutionFolder = GetSolutionFolder(_solution);
  }