# Create a Solution Folder in a Visual Studio Project Template

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, project-template

I have created a multi project Visual Studio Temploate following these instructions:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185308.aspx.

This works fine and I can see my two projects in Visual Studio when I select my project template from the File-->New Project option.

[image]

Now I want to add another two projects but I now want the projects to appear under different folders like so:

[image]

How can I modify the .vstemplate file to make the solution folders appear?  I see from this link [Add solution folder to visual studio project template](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9207537/add-solution-folder-to-visual-studio-project-template) that I should use a Wizard (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185301.aspx) but I really dont know how to use this to simply create two folders.  All help is appreciated.

**EDIT**
I have followed this example http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms185301.aspx and I can now add folders to my project by doing this:

```
 _DTE _dte;
 Solution2 _solution;

public void RunStarted(object automationObject, Dictionary<string, string> replacementsDictionary, WizardRunKind runKind, object[] customParams)
    {     
        _dte = automationObject as _DTE;
    }

public void RunFinished()
    {
        _solution = (Solution2)_dte.Solution;

        _solution.AddSolutionFolder("MyFolder1");
        _solution.AddSolutionFolder("MyFolder2");    
    }
```

But what I want to do is add my projects under the folders.  They are just appearing on top at present.
How do I do this?

Comment: Do you have solution of this question?

Answer (score 5):

programmatically, no! I´ve not do it ...  only changing the .vstemplate file

```
<SolutionFolder Name="Math Classes">
            <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="MyFolder1">
                3rdpartyProj\MyTemplate.vstemplate
            </ProjectTemplateLink>
            <ProjectTemplateLink ProjectName="MyFolder2">
                3rdpartyProj\MyTemplate.vstemplate
            </ProjectTemplateLink>
        </SolutionFolder>
```

[SolutionFolder](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms171399.aspx)

I think this is what you are looking for?